# Autolayout, constraints, iOS ... как правильнее?

Tags: objective-c, ios, autolayout, constraints

Доброго времени суток!

Как выставить констранты для разных UITableViewCell, чтобы можно было скрыть "группу 2" и при этом "группа 3" встала на её место?

Либо это делается в разных xib'ах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему нельзя сделать "группа 3" всем view свойство .hidden = YES; ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте внимательно вопрос. Необходимо чтобы можно было скрыть "группу 2" (синяя), при этом "группа 3" (розовая) должна встать на место её место.

Comment: Я предлагаю манипулировать свойством вью чтобы скрывать третью группу, а на месте второй показывать то, что должно быть на третьей. Разделить вью от функционала. Таким же образом можно не показывать вторую и третью или вовсе все скрыть. При этом можно менять цвет как угодно.

Comment: Цветом обозначены группы для удобства зрительного восприятия и понимания сути вопроса. Оказалось все просто. Если необходимо, могу ответить.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/). Он только под iOS 9, но есть масса классов, имитирующих его поведение под 7 и 8 версии, например OAStackView или TZStackView.

Если же требуется выполнить эту задачу именно с помощью autolayout, то придется объединить группы в UIView и манипулировать либо их размерами, либо расстоянием между ними.

Answer (score 0):

Решений много, в частности, просто не заполнять не нужную группу.
Но если надо именно constraints, то просто объединить каждую группу viewхой, выставлять константу ширины view в ноль, если надо скрыть.

А гораздо лучше объединить это все в массив аутлетов, заполнять последовательно в зависимости от данных, тем самым не заполняя не нужные группы.